# Is there an ld-linux.so equivalent for mac?

Tags: linux, macos, libraries

I'm using the following command on Linux to change the default library path temporarily for the program being run:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /home/me/libs./myProgram
```

This runs myProgram and makes it check /home/me/libs first for its dynamically linked libraries.

So I want to do this on Mac too.. is there an equivalent? I'd like to avoid setting environment variables if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MacOS X equivalent to the Linux `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`... so, you should be able to execute the following:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/me/libs ./myProgram
```

This will assign a new value for this environment variable for just this run of the program.  (which is pretty much what you you're doing by executing ld.so (which is quite unconventional, btw))

Comment: This is not quite equivalent, as this will impact all child process of the started process, whereas the ld-linux command only affects the process being executed.